# Does a large-sized div affect on not showing Google Ads on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ads, adsense

My website has a main article div, which has a width of 2358px. It is too big when loading it on mobile devices. But I am scaling it down dynamically when it’s loaded on a smartphone. Will Google Ads appear inside that big div? If the Ad has a width of 300px as it’s a phone Ad, then it will look very tiny. It doesn’t mater if it’s tiny, I can fix this. But my concern is, will Google be able to display Ads calculating the size from a big 2358px main container or should I set a small like 500px parent div for the Ad unit code? I kind of hoping that the Ads should appear on both cases even if the parent div is too big 2358px in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ads with a fixed size, but I would recommend you to set all Ads into their own parent container, especially for better styling and width/height adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use responsive or fluid ads, as long as the parent container div meets the minimum size requirements for Google Ads, the Ads should appear fine, is it like that? The big size div on mobile devices will not interfere with ad size calculation? Please check the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73238547/should-i-use-a-parent-div-for-adsense-ad-units

Comment: If the ad size is set to responsive, it will adjust itself to the parent element or smaller. As long as these sizes are in the ad-size requirements and there are ads available for this size, it should work.